# ビジュアルプログラミングを開始できない。

Tags: aibo-visual-programming

「開発を始める」をクリックすると、aiboビジュアルプログラミングの動作環境の画面で

> こちらの機能は、お使いのブラウザに対応していません

と表示されます。

windowsのバージョンは8.1、Google Chromeのバージョンは79.09.3945.88で最新版となっています。プログラミングを開始するには、どうすればよいのでしょうか？

Comment: ホームページを見ますと、Google Chrome ver.63以降と書いてありますので、Google Chromeを古いバージョンにすると動くかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

aibo ビジュアルプログラミングの動作環境につきましては、aiboオーナーサポートへお問い合わせください。

https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact

「aiboの飼い方、ご購入前の相談など、aiboに関するすべてのお問い合わせは以下のaibo専用窓口へお問い合わせください。」

・メールでのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry_mail/?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/contact/_mail

上記リンク先において、注意事項に同意いただいた上、
　「同意してメールで問い合わせる」ボタンを押してください。

・チャットでのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/aibo/inquiry/chat.html

上記リンク先にある「上記内容を確認してチャットサポートを開始する」を押してください。

・LINE でのお問い合わせ
　https://www.sony.jp/support/inquiry_line.html

LINE公式アカウントから、お問い合わせをいただけます。
　リンク先にある「友だち追加」ボタンをクリックするか、「QRコード」を読み取ってください。

また、Stackoverflow はソニーの外部サイトであり、
質問はプログラミングのことに限定していただきますようお願いいたします。
詳しくはこちらをご参照ください。

https://aibo.sony.jp/support/contact.html?s_pid=jp_aibo_/support/_contact#devevisu

・質問の例
　「〇〇のプログラムを実行したいのですが、どうすればできますか？」
　「APIでエラーが発生します。原因は何でしょうか？」

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム